# Error Pull Image when Run Installation Cloud Pak for Data 2.5.0 on OCP 4.3

Tags: cloud-pak-for-data

Error When Pulling Image 'cpdoperator:v2.5.0.0-68'?

I Try Run The Installation again but Still Have Error Like Below:
[image: ror]

this version the CPD Installer and my OCP what im using:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem soloved.

Reason:
cloudpak4data-ee-v2.5.0.0.tgz downloaded by executing CP4D_EE_Installer_V2.5.bin has been updated recently, but  cpdoperator:v2.5.0.0-68 is not available from cp.icr.io/cp/cpd so far.

walk around:
 Using old version cloudpak4data-ee-v2.5.0.0.tgz  to install